# Execute a command after successfully SSH connection

Tags: python, linux, ssh, terminal, raspberry-pi

I think I may of been googling this stuff wrong, however I was wondering if I could have my raspberry Pi execute a command after I connect to it via SSH.

Workflow:
1) SSH into Pi via terminal
2) Once logged in, the Pi executes a command to display the current temperature (I already know of this command)

The pi already outputs

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.10.25+ #622 PREEMPT Fri Jan 3 18:41:00 GMT 2014 armv6l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Fri Jul 11 15:11:35 2014
```

I could be misunderstanding this all together, perhaps even have the command executed and shown in the dialog above.

Comment: it depends on the type of shell, but you can add commands to the user .bashrc, .profile (or whatever your shell uses).

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the motd which is quite common on various linux distros. This is not in python (but can be). The motd runs multiple commands on login via SSH and constructs a message which it outputs to the user. More information on this (which actually has temperature listed) can be found here: [Rapberry Pi Welcome Message](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=23440). The problem is this will likely change slightly depending on linux distros. A good git repo which has a nice message can also be found here: [Raspberry Pi Motd](https://github.com/gagle/raspberrypi-motd)

Answer (score 0):

Yup, this can been done.  The method that I am aware of utilizes `subprocess` https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html.  As long as you know the name of the python script and the arguments (if any) you can pass them into `subprocess`.  Here is an example of how to connect via python ssh script (taken from http://python-for-system-administrators.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ssh.html):

```
    import subprocess
    import sys

    HOST="www.example.org"
    # Ports are handled in ~/.ssh/config since we use OpenSSH
    COMMAND="uname -a"

    ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
                   shell=False,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
    if result == []:
        error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
        print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
    else:
        print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append the command to the ssh-command.

`ssh user@server "echo test"`

`"echo test"` is executed on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a command from bash without actually logging into the other computer by placing the command after the shh command:

```
$ ssh pi@pi_addr touch wat.txt
```

Would create the text file ~/wat.txt.

This is a little cumbersome for automation however since as password must be provided so you can set a public/private RSA-key on your computer in order to be able to login to your pi remotely without a password. Simply do the following:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
    Generating public/private rsa key pair.
    Enter file in which to save the key (/home/a/.ssh/id_rsa):
    Created directory '/home/a/.ssh'.
    Enter passphase (empty for no passphrase):
    Enter the same passphrase again:
$ssh pi@pi_addr mkdir -p .ssh
$cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh pi@pi_addr 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Don't enter a passphrase and leave everything default when running ssh-keygen. Now you will be able to rn ssh pi@pi_addr without enter a password.

Example python file:

```
import subprocess

SERVER = "pi@pi_addr"
subprocess.call("ssh pi@pi_addr touch wat.txt")
```